# Need a regex to add a space before and after a "point", but no on decimal numbers

Tags: php, regex

i need a regex that replaces the char "." with a blank space before and after " . ", but only if the point is not part of a number (decimal point):

example:

```
test. of my country.brazil, should be 38.45
```

It should return:

```
test . of my country . brazil, should be 38.45
```

Any one can help ?

Thanks

Comment: Here you are `/\D\.\D/`

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/a5yJmB/1

Comment: Based on the description result should be `test .  of my country . brazil, should be 38.45`. Two spaces before `of my country`. Not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<?php

$regex = '/([^0-9])\s?\.\s?([^0-9])/';
$string = 'test. of my country.brazil, should be 38.45';
$replace = '$1 . $2';
echo preg_replace($regex, $replace, $string);
//test . of my country . brazil, should be 38.45
```

Comment: You did it !! Thanks very much !

Comment: @costamatrix This regex assumes there should be a character following and preceding dot. So it matches neither on `str.` nor on `.str`. Take care.